# Windows Phone 7 Emulator Does Not Run

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am trying to install the Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools on Windows 7 Professional x64.
The installation goes smoothly and no errors are reported however when trying to start the emulator from the Start menu nothing happens.

I have managed to install the tools successfully on Windows 7 Home Premium x64 and Windows 7 Professional x86.

Also when I create a Windows Phone project in Visual Studio 2010 the Emulator is not listed in the drop-down box for debugging.

I have tried several reinstalls of Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools and Visual Studio but the problems persist.

Does anyone know what is causing these issues or of a way that I could diagnose the problem?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First two things I would check, is make sure that you have the file:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhone\v7.0\Emulation\Images\WM70C1.en-US.bin
```

Then, assuming you have that file open a command line and go to the directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\1.0
```

Then run the following command:

```
xde.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhone\v7.0\Emulation\Images\WM70C1.en-US.bin
```

What this will do is tell you whether it's an emulator problem, or a visual studio problem.

If it's visual studio, the only thing I can think of is try and run it as administrator (VS that is) to see if it's a permissions problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have followed the steps you mentioned but the emulator still does not run when using the command line. So this means it will be a problem with the emulator? I have installed the October 2010 patch for the Developer Tools also but that has made no difference.

Comment: In addition to the path to the image, you need to pass a virtual machine ID (aka GUID) to the XDE in order to boot an independent instance (outside VS).

Comment: what if the image file is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my laptop. The problem has to do with me not having a directx 10 compatable video card [directx 10](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsphone7series/thread/FDE4C415-44C5-4837-B1CD-E09727A75B92).  Also this is [Microsofts troubleshooting info](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/c4754ebd-f688-4c33-972a-a578b9db12ff)

> The emulator requires DX10, at least to fully support XNA (although you are testing via a Silverlight app). It could be that there is some issue related to the video card in your computer.  Check the video driver settings to confirm that the card is DX10 and not throttled down. I believe there are instructions in the documentation regarding how to test DirectX settings.

Comment: I had already checked my DirectX settings and my card is DirectX 11